# angualr2 http pauses gif

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I have just entered into angular2 world and i am facing this problem where i am trying to show a loader before the initiation of http request and hide it after the work is done with the data received from http request. Problem is that the loader is a gif which shows but doesn't play as it is supposed to do. The http initiation pauses the gif somehow.  Pasting the block of code in the post. Please help me and let me know where i am going wrong.

```
if(this.counter<3){
            $('#table_loading').css('display','block');          
            this.counter++;       
             this.datamanager.fetchData().subscribe((data)=>{          
            $('#table_loading').hide();
            })       
    }
//here is fetchData 
 fetchData(){
    return this.http.get('/assets/data.json').map(
      (res) => res.json()
    )
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I never had any luck with gifs, even using settimeouts etc. They just get stuck I don't know why. I resolved myself to use css animations instead. For instance even font-awesome `fa-spin` is better.

Comment: Please provide plunker.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to mix jquery code with angular code. You can use angular's structural directives (*ngIf,...) to show, hide, dynamically change style in component's template. Please provide more code!

Comment: @Faly Thanks for the review,  i will remove this jquery code. 
And the problem got solved. There was some issue with the data handling code which was causing the whole problem.

Comment: @Sebas Unfortunately, CSS animations also get stuck when using Angular2 and other scripts inside it. GIFs and CSS animations freeze when Angular2 scripts load.